# A clause for an undetermined area which can covers a line

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

I wrote:

> We don't suppose a fixed area to cover the top edge of a pallet car,
>   because minor changes in the angle or the focal length of the monitoring camera, or minor differences in the positions of the pallet cars can cause disadjustment.

However I am told to write the paper from the perspective a third person. Then I changed it to:

> The area to cover the top edge of a pallet car is not supposed to be fixed, because minor changes in the angle or the focal length of the camera, or small differences in the positions of different pallet cars can cause readjustment

My first question is if they are equivalent. Also, for the first sentence I don't know which of the following is better:

- The area **to cover** the top edge of a pallet car is not supposed to be fixed.
- The area **that can cover** the top edge of a pallet car is not supposed to be fixed.
- The area **that covers** the top edge of a pallet car is not supposed to be fixed.
- The area **for covering** the top edge of a pallet car is not supposed to be fixed.

Do they all have the same meaning? which is more natural?
In fact we look for an area in the image, which covers the top edge of an object. it is not determined in the first place.

In the image of bellow suppose the filled box is the pallet car and the blue rectangle is the area to cover its top edge. In A this situation holds but it may not hold in B, if we suppose a fixed coordinates for the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: I think your second sentence serves your intention better by expressing the possibility of using that area. BTW I didn't understand the meaning of _area_ here. Is it a part that is attached to the car?

Comment: @Yuri I modified the question.  It is in an image.

Comment: I should say _no, they don't have the same meaning_. I think it will be helpful to attach a **picture** for those who want to answer the question. Still I can't get the meaning of _area_ here. Besides, this area is going to be fixed at the end or not. These all, _I think_, can be a contributing factor to which sentence to be used.

Comment: This is perilously close to proofreading, @Ahmad ... But the third is most idiomatic.

Comment: Wait, this is about image processing, right?  You should say *mask*, not area.  "The mask that covers the top edge of the pallet car..."

Comment: @JohnFeltz maybe the region is better word.

Comment: I'd suggest starting the sentence with "Since minor changes..."   And I don't understand what is meant by "the area that covers the top edge". The edge is a line, and I'm not sure how an area covers an edge line. Includes it?  By *disadjustment* do you mean "visual distortion of the image"?

Comment: And **assumed** might be better than **supposed**, since "not supposed to be" can mean "is intentionally not".

Comment: @TRomano I  added an image to the question. I means to include it. instead of disadjusment we may use readjustment. When the pallet car is not in the right frame of camera

Comment: @TRomano I finally wrote *The next stage is to detect bending and to measure the degree of bending. for this purpose, we first identify a region in the image that includes the top edge. Then, a curve is fitted through the white pixels in the region. The coordinates of such a region cannot be fixed, because minor changes in the angle or the focal length of the camera, or small differences in the positions of different pallet cars would require readjustment*. Did I use *would require* correctly?

Comment: You say **would require** but I expected simply **require**. The coordinates of the region cannot be fixed because {certain conditions} require the region's position to be adjustable.